# PowerShell task to run Background Job (Start-Job)

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I try to run `Start-Job` inside a PowerShell VSTS Task TFS 2018.1 OnPrem.

I test that script starts to run using the `Receive-Job`.
When the task exits the script stops.

In the PowerShell task I run the following:

```
Start-Job -FilePath "C:\build\BGGetFromNuGet.ps1" -ArgumentList "C:\build"
```

Is it possible to that script will continue to to run in the background while the task has finished?
Is my only option is to Use a Scheduled Task ?
The script is Downloading a big amount of data that is needed for latest stages of the build.

Comment: You forgot to ask your question. Is something not working? How *exactly* is it "not working" (i.e. what result did you expect, and what result did you actually get)?

Comment: The question is clear - in VSTS build, when the PowerShell task finished running the background job also stop (I think you need to return the VSTS on the title).

Comment: Please stop putting tags in the subject of your question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the question is regarding VSTS PowerShell task - (you can see it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/index?view=vsts), is not just Powershell task, is VSTS task.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk And it is correctly tagged tag:vsts. Tags do not belong in the subject. One could argue that the subject should be "VSTS task to ..." rather than "PowerShell task to ...", but tag-ish additions to the subject are a no-no.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I do not agree with you but you are more experienced than me... in the end is vsts powershell task, not a powershell task and not vsts task.

Answer (score 1):

Use `start-process` command to launch the script. This will make sure that the launched job keeps running when the task is finished. But the job will be closed when the build is finished.

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-file C:\build\BGGetFromNuGet.ps1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple api app to run these jobs, then send the API request to that application during build/release to run these jobs.